# Selenium No Such Element Exception - Python

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to automate some stuff behind some hyperlinks from my university's SAP Portal. I figured using `Selenium` is the way to go here. But it turns out most of the web elements there are `faked` and created from `JavaScript`, that is probably why webdriver cannot **SEE** them.

Here is what I have to click:

```py
<a class="urLnkDragRelate" id="Link6c5f851b" ct="LN" st="" tabindex="0" ti="0" title="Feedback Form" onkeydown="return (sapUrMapi_Link_activate('Link6c5f851b',event))" href="javascript:void(0)" target="" onclick="return htmlbDoEvent(this,'C','onclick','0','htmlb_222143_0',6,1,'',0);">
  <span class="urFontStd">
    <span ct="TV" class="urTxtStd">Feedback Form</span>
  </span>
</a>
```

Here is the page source : https://pastebin.com/Dpc36nxL

Screenshot for understanding: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1BM5.jpg

I tried to use a workaround, by using `ActionChains` to open up developer console, and inject an artificial CLICK on the desired element, but even that failed because when I try to inject JavaScript at the end, the link here changes each time.
`document.querySelector("#Link5908e99d")`

Something like this:

```
assert "Feedback Form" in driver.page_source

# open up the developer console
driver.send_keys(keys.Keys.CTRL+keys.Keys.SHIFT+'i')
driver.perform()

time.sleep(3)

action.send_keys(keys.Keys.ENTER)

# inject the JavaScript...
action.send_keys("document.querySelector("#Link5908e99d").click()"+keys.Keys.ENTER)

action.perform()
```

How do I go forward with this?

**The solution was to switch to the iframe which totally went unnoticed and then find the element using its relative XPath from the iframe.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think link id is dynamic here and if you want to click on a element then please use below xpath.

```
locateClick= WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//a[contains(text(),'Link')]")))
locateClick.click();
```

Comment: returns `in until raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)`

Comment: Can you share site if possible ?

Comment: It's a university portal (requires login), I've shared the full source in my post.

Comment: sorry but I am not able to identify your element as per your site https://pastebin.com/cMHA3Ftk

Comment: Realised that the source wasn't copied completely because Chrome doesn't have that functionality yet. I did get the full source though and it's updated in the post.

Comment: Try to switch to frame  driver.switch_to.frame(ivuFRm_page0ivu3) and then find element

Comment: Passing the relative XPath from the iframe worked like a charm. Thanks a ton!